# SwiftUI @State variable not updating view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am very very new to swift development, and I'm trying to follow multiple different online tutorials to try and build a sign in page. Unfortunately all of the different views and models haven't slotted together well, and I'm having some issues.

The code below seems to work, apart from the ErrorView displaying. This code doesn't compile when the variables **alert** and **error** are @Published variable. It gives me the error ``Failed to produce diagnostics for expression". When I change them both to @State variables they don't update the view.

```
class AppViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var signedIn = false
    @Published var alert = false;
    @Published var error = ""
    let auth = Auth.auth();

    func signIn(email: String, password: String){
        auth.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { [weak self] result, error in
            guard result != nil, error == nil else{
                self?.error = error!.localizedDescription
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                self?.alert.toggle()
                return
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.signedIn = true
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SignInView: View {
    @State var email = ""
    @State var password = ""
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AppViewModel
       
    var body: some View {      
        VStack {
            if viewModel.alert {
                //SHOW ERROR        
                ErrorView(alert: viewModel.$alert, error: viewModel.$error)
                Text("errors")        
            }
            //SHOW SIGN IN FORM
            //THERE IS CODE HERE TO CALL THE AUTH FUNCTIONS VIA BUTTONS ETC BUT APPARENTLY I'M NOT ALLOWED TO PUT THE WHOLE FILE IN THIS QUESTION
        }
    }
}
```

If I used published variables I get an error `Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please file a bug report` at `var body: some View`. If I use state variables then the ErrorView is never shown.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic. You have way too much code in your question, which makes it much harder for anyone else to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I have done this now.

Comment: That error means that your code is broken in some way that the compiler can't identify. I would recommend commenting blocks of code until it compiles in order to figure out where is the offending block. Beyond that there isn't a lot we can figure out from that error message.

Comment: @ArianeHine Without `ErrorView`, we cannot solve the problem. Did you mean `$viewModel.alert` instead of `viewModel.$alert`?

Comment: You should also try to create appropriate `Swift`  file for each important `View`

Comment: This error only happens when I change the variables alert and error to Published instead of State. @EmilioPelaez. When the variables are tagged as state the code compiles but the UI does not change when the state variable changes

Comment: @ArianeHine That is because State is for structs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

`ErrorView(alert: viewModel.$alert, error: viewModel.$error)`

to this

`ErrorView(alert: $viewModel.alert, error: $viewModel.error)`

#### Tips

Almost always, you should move any variables to your View Model. For example you have `email and password` as @State variables in your view. It makes much more sense to move those to your View Model. Why? You may later need to access them inside of a function or method in your VM itself. It's much easier to handle that if the data is already there. In your view you'd access it as `Text(viewModel.email)` or `Text(viewModel.password)`. However if you need to validate that, inside your view model, it'll be readily accessible.

Answer (score 4):

You should change `viewModel.$alert` to `$viewModel.alert`.

When you were using `@State`, the type of `viewModel.$alert` was `Binding<Bool>`. Now that you have changed it to `@Published`, like it should be, that type is now `Published<Bool>.Publisher`.

When you use `$viewModel.alert`, the type is `Binding<Bool>` correctly again.